# Google finance returns null

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I am using curl to retrieve the value of current share price and i have created several cron jobs which update the value of the share every 20 minutes or so. Yesterday it was working fine but suddenly from today it is returning null object and i an using curl for value retrieval.

Here is the code:

```
$sourceURL = 'http://www.google.com/finance/info?infotype=infoquoteall&q='.$row[1].':'.$main_id;

    echo $sourceURL."<br/>";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5; // set to zero for no timeout
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sourceURL);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$sourceData = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json = str_replace("\n", "", $sourceData);

 //Remove //, [ and ] to build qualified string  
$data = substr($json, 4, strlen($json) -5);
```

//decode JSON data

```
$json_output = json_decode(utf8_decode($data));
var_dump($json_output);
```

//Output Stock price
  //update_in_DB returns the query string like in the bottom

```
$query=update_in_DB($json_output,$main_id);
$result_query=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
if($result_query===false)
{
    echo mysqli_error($dbc)."<br/>";
}
echo "done<br/>";`
```

this was working fine as i said but now update_in_DB reurns this:

```
UPDATE `stock_table`
SET `stock_curr_val`=0, `stock_change`=0, `stock_change_p`=0, stock_open_val`=0, `stock_hi_val`=0, `stock_low_val`=0, `stock_volume`='0', stock_hi_52`=0, stock_low_52`=0, `stock_market_cap`='0'
WHERE `stock_symbol`='20MICRONS';
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "but suddenly" is a good indicator that the error sits somewhere between chair-back and keyboard. There must be a difference somewhere as nothing does change suddenly. Please narrow your question to the relevant parts. Is it a problem with MySQL or CURL?

Comment: as per me its curl as it returns NULL

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: it is always returning operation completed without any error